# How to make an async button click update a TextView dynamically with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin

In Xamarin Native Android app I am calling methodOne() and getting some details. After this I want to updated the details to text view and then calls the methodTwo(). After executing MethodTwo I have to clear the text details from text view. I tried with
 RunOnUiThread(() => tColorDetail.SetText("text", TextView.BufferType.Normal));
The details are displaying after finishing all the methods it is not showing immediately after executing MethodOne(). 
What is missing here? 
.....................................................

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;
    ticket Ticket;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button bClick= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bSub);
        try {
        bClick.Click += delegate {

            Job Job;
            Action act = new Action();
            EditText Address = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Address);
            act.Address = Address.Text.ToString();

            if (!ValidateIPv4(act.Address))
            {
                ShowMessage("Invalid IP");
            }
            else
            {//TextView Mode = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Mode);
                string httpUrl = act.iPAddress ;
                Ticket = act.ExecuteTicket(httpUrl, "Ticket");
                //RunOnUiThread(() => tColorMode.SetText("text", TextView.BufferType.Normal));
               // this.RunOnUiThread(() => setTicket(true));
                  setStatus(" Ticket : Success", true);
                 setTicket(true);
                //tColorMode.SetText("text",TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                //tColorMode.Invalidate();
                Job = act.executeJob(httpUrl, Ticket);
                setStatus(" Job : Success", true);
                act.File(httpUrl, Ticket, Job);
                setStatus("File Retrieval : Success", true);
                setTicket(false);
                setStatus("File Retrieval : Success", false);
            }
        };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ShowMessage(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    public bool ValidateIPv4(string ipString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipString))
        {
            return false;
        }

        string[] splitValues = ipString.Split('.');
        if (splitValues.Length != 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
     }

    public  void setTicket(bool b)
    {
        //TextView tMode = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tMode);
        // tMode.SetText("text",TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        RunOnUiThread(() => { 
        TextView tMode = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Mode);
        tColorMode.SetText("text",TextView.BufferType.Normal);// b==true?Ticket.getProcessing():"";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tRes)).Text =  b == true ? Ticket.getHeight().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tFormat)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getFormat().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tOrode)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getType().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tRot)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getValue().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tSource)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getSource().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tSize)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getAutoDetect().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tExpo)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getAuto().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tSharp)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getSharp().ToString() : "";
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tComp)).Text = b == true ? Ticket.getComp().ToString() : "";
        //tColorMode.Invalidate();
    }); }
    private void ShowMessage(string msg)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();

        dialog.SetMessage(msg);
        dialog.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
        {
            dialog.Cancel();
        });
        dialog.Show();
    }
    private void setStatus(string status,bool b)
    {
        ((TextView)this.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tStatus)).Text = b == true ? status : " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update with relevant codes?

Comment: Can you share the code you've already done

Comment: Please find  the code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the full code it is tricky to give you an answer but

```
Ticket = act.ExecuteTicket(httpUrl, "Ticket");
```

this line has the potential to take a while to complete if it performs network operations and probably runs in a background thread not to freeze the UI.

Presumably when you get to

```
    // this.RunOnUiThread(() => setTicket(true));setStatus(" Ticket : Success", true);
 setTicket(true);
```

the act.ExecuteTicket call might not have finished

also if there are async operations taking place in

```
Job = act.executeJob(httpUrl, Ticket);
```

it could take a while to complete

All taken into consideration, you could probably be getting to

```
setTicket(false);
setStatus("File Retrieval : Success", false);
```

before the first calls finish

It could be worth checking

ANSWER UPDATE after discussion in comments:

Since your problem is that your asynchronous calls are taking a long time and you are experiencing "race conditions" because of it (your UI thread is proceeding with the updates on the TextViews before it should), you can solve the situation by changing your button click `delegate` to an `async delegate`, and forcing an `await` on the long operations' result before proceeding.

```
bClick.Click += async delegate {

               //...
               Job = await act.executeJob(httpUrl, Ticket);
               //...
    }
```

Comment: Hi @goldneb, Thanks for the response. act.execute is a executing synchronously and the values are getting assigned to the variable before going to next method.When I debug the code the values are getting assigned but not displaying in UI.After getting out of button click only the UI is changing..

Comment: @user2235253 yup I thought so ;) have you tried to change the "delegate" to "async delegate" and put  "await" before long method calls?

Comment: @goldneb you are not gold you are diamond :)Thanks after changing to await its working...

Comment: @user2235253 nice! I will edit the answer to include these last details later ;) 
I'm glad I could help. Cheers!